# Linked servers and access rights

Tags: mysql, t-sql, linked-server

I have two databases namely MSSQL and Mysql on different servers. My requirement was to sync data from MSSQL to Mysql. In other words any changes done to MSSql should get reflected in Mysql but not vice versa. So I created linked server to connect the database and created triggers to push data to MYSql if there is any insert or update done to MSSql. Now there are few financial tables present in MSSQL database. I do not want to give access to those financial tables to users who use MySql database. Any idea on how to restrict the access?
Also, I would like to know if there is any other better way than linked servers.

P.S. I googled and found SSIS is the other option but I was unable to find any more options.

Answer (score 0):

To deny access to specific tables in MySQL, use `REVOKE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html

In TSQL, the command is `DENY`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx

In your case, though, if the MySQL users should not see certain tables, then doesn't that just mean that those tables should not have the triggers to replicate the data on MySQL?

If replication is still necessary, and you are dealing with a large number of tables, you might also consider pushing the restricted tables to a separate target database, which could simplify access restrictions.